# How to calculate average from multiple values in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a mapper that emit key/value pairs(composite keys and composite values separated by comma).

e.g

**key:** a,b,c,d **Value:** 1,2,3,4,5

**key:** a1,b1,c1,d1 **Value:** 5,4,3,2,1

...

...

**key:** a,b,c,d **Value:** 5,4,3,2,1

I could easily SUM these values using reduceByKey.

e.g

```
reduceByKey(new Function2<String, String, String>() {

        @Override
        public String call(String value1, String value2) {
            String oldValue[] = value1.toString().split(",");
            String newValue[] = value2.toString().split(",");

            int iFirst = Integer.parseInt(oldValue[0]) + Integer.parseInt(newValue[0]);
            int iSecond = Integer.parseInt(oldValue[1]) + Integer.parseInt(newValue[1]);
            int iThird = Integer.parseInt(oldValue[2]) + Integer.parseInt(newValue[2]);
            int iFourth = Integer.parseInt(oldValue[3]) + Integer.parseInt(newValue[3]);
            int iFifth = Integer.parseInt(oldValue[4]) + Integer.parseInt(newValue[4]);

            return iFirst  + "," + iSecond + ","
                    + iThird+ "," + iFourth+ "," + iFifth;

        }
    });
```

But the problem is how do I find average of just one of these values. Lets assume I want to SUM iFirst, iSecond, iThird and iFourth but I want to find Average of iFifth. How do i do it? With a simple key/value pairs I could use mapValues function but not sure how I could do it with my example. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `foldByKey` function to resolve this issue.

Comment: can you share your code on how you solved this using foldByKey?